# How to use mobile app into whatsapp share link?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, mobile, whatsapp

How do you use an HTML link to open the whatsapp on a mobile app ?
this link works on website
Example link:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F51533526%2Fhow-to-use-html-link-into-whatsapp-mobile-app%2F51533716%3Fnoredirect%3D1">Whatsapp Share </a>
```

This link is failing in the WhatsApp mobile app.

This is the error message:

```
ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

I want to solve this problem on the front end side.

Comment: same example=>  phone number open de whatsapp app same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use mobile app into whatsapp share link working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607703/how-to-use-mobile-app-into-whatsapp-share-link-working)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's not recognized as a valid "href" atribute, try it out with a valid one and see what happens.

Comment: this is example link , this link works on website but not working whatsapp app

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
whatsapp://send?text=HeyThere!
```

Comment: @korkut it should work after this change. Make sure to clean your browser cache and check the link was updated.

Comment: for mobile website use working but  web site  application into    link not working

Comment: @korkut what do you mean "web site application into link"? please give more details on what you are doing

Comment: web site link =>  <a href="whatsapp://send?text=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F51533526%2Fhow-to-use-html-link-into-whatsapp-mobile-app%2F51533716%3Fnoredirect%3D1">Whatsapp Share </a>

Comment: @korkut I have answered your original question and the following one. If you change the question you should open a new question, not edit the existing one.

Comment: @S.I. this is not a link to the answer. it's the suggested fix of his original wrongly typed link in his code that was wrong. You can't see it cause the guy just keeps changing it in the question text.

Comment: Okay, apologize then!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
whatsapp://send?text=message
```