# How to use mobile app into whatsapp share link working?

Tags: android, node.js, mobile, whatsapp

How do you use an HTML link to open the whatsapp on a mobile app ? this link works on website Example link:`<a href="whatsapp://send?text=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F51533526%2Fhow-to-use-html-link-into-whatsapp-mobile-app%2F51533716%3Fnoredirect%3D1">Whatsapp Share </a>`

This link is failing in the WhatsApp mobile app.

This is the error message:

> ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

(same error =>  app into phone number click)
I want to solve this problem on the front end side.

Comment: Do you want to share a text or image or just want to open Whatsapp?

Comment: I want to open text , Click the link in the app , opened whatsapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code directly shares the Text to the Whatsapp app using Intent.

```
Intent textIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
textIntent.setType("text/plain");
textIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
textIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your text here");
startActivity(textIntent);
```

Comment: is this problem solution back-end side ?(android)

Comment: @korkut No, you have enter this code in the Android app.